# A tool to export / search inside a .pst file?

Tags: outlook, data-recovery

I was handed an old .pst file, and as you can guess, inside that file there is supposed to be an important email.

I have no access to a computer with Microsoft Outlook installed. Does anyone know of a good tool to locate this email inside the .pst file and/or export all emails from there?

Thanks,
Amir.

Comment: Do you know if it's encrypted / compressed?

Comment: Product recommendations are off topic per the updated [FAQ](http://serverfault.com/faq).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can download Outlook as part of  a [60 day free trial of Office](http://office.microsoft.com/suites) from Microsoft. Install it in a VM if you don't want to mess up your main computer.

If you don't want to do that for whatever reason, there are some standalone programs that claim to be able to handle PSTs without Outlook installed:

- http://www.recoverytoolbox.com/pst_viewer.html
- http://pstwalker.com/pstwalker.html

Or if you're using something Unixy, have a look at readpst:

- http://alioth.debian.org/projects/libpst/

Answer (score 0):

Outlook.

There's also a program called MailStore that will extract PST data and export to PDF or .eml, but I think that it requires Outlook to run. That was about 18 months ago when I made the Windows->Mac transition.